# create plot for each case in spss

Tags: plot, spss

based on this site http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476602
I want to create a spider chart in SPSS from 6 variables. However, I want to create it for each row or case from my Dataset.

Example:

```
id  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
1    4     4    3      4     2      1
2    3     4    2      4     4      4
3    4     1    3      1     4      4
4    1     1    2      4     1      4
5    4     3    4      1     2      2
```

The output should be 5 spider charts with the name id.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to not bother with parallel coordinates, but simply reshape your data so `Var1 TO Var6` are in the same column.

```
DATA LIST FREE / ID Var1 TO Var6.
BEGIN DATA
1    4     4    3      4     2      1
2    3     4    2      4     4      4
3    4     1    3      1     4      4
4    1     1    2      4     1      4
5    4     3    4      1     2      2
END DATA.

*Reshape and make graph - much easier.
VARSTOCASES /MAKE Var FROM Var1 TO Var6 /INDEX VarID (Var).
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=VarID Var ID
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: VarID=col(source(s), name("VarID"), unit.category())
  DATA: ID=col(source(s), name("ID"), unit.category())
  DATA: Var=col(source(s), name("Var"))
  COORD: polar(dim(1,2))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("VarID"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Var"))
  ELEMENT: line(position(VarID*Var), split(ID), color(ID), closed(), 
           preserveStraightLines())
END GPL.
```

To make these individual graphs (so each ID has their own plot and they aren't all superimposed on the same graph) you can either use small multiples:

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=VarID Var ID
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: VarID=col(source(s), name("VarID"), unit.category())
  DATA: ID=col(source(s), name("ID"), unit.category())
  DATA: Var=col(source(s), name("Var"))
  COORD: polar(dim(1,2), wrap())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("VarID"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Var"))
  ELEMENT: line(position(VarID*Var*ID), closed(), preserveStraightLines())
END GPL.
```

Or you can use `SPLIT FILE`:

```
SPLIT FILE BY ID.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=VarID Var ID
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: VarID=col(source(s), name("VarID"), unit.category())
  DATA: ID=col(source(s), name("ID"), unit.category())
  DATA: Var=col(source(s), name("Var"))
  COORD: polar(dim(1,2))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("VarID"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Var"))
  ELEMENT: line(position(VarID*Var), closed(), preserveStraightLines())
END GPL.
SPLIT FILE OFF.
```

---

With the original data you *could* use parallel coordinates, pretty much the same as the given tech-note you listed, it is much more annoying though to format all of the axes. Example below.

```
DATA LIST FREE / ID Var1 TO Var6.
BEGIN DATA
1    4     4    3      4     2      1
2    3     4    2      4     4      4
3    4     1    3      1     4      4
4    1     1    2      4     1      4
5    4     3    4      1     2      2
END DATA.
DATASET NAME Temp.
EXECUTE.

*Using parrallel coordinate plot.
FORMATS ID Var1 TO Var6 (F1.0).
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=ID Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: ID=col(source(s), name("ID"), unit.category())
  DATA: Var1=col(source(s), name("Var1"))
  DATA: Var2=col(source(s), name("Var2"))
  DATA: Var3=col(source(s), name("Var3"))
  DATA: Var4=col(source(s), name("Var4"))
  DATA: Var5=col(source(s), name("Var5"))
  DATA: Var6=col(source(s), name("Var6"))
  COORD: polar(parallel())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Var1"), delta(1), start(1))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Var2"), delta(1), start(1))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(3), label("Var3"), delta(1), start(1))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(4), label("Var4"), delta(1), start(1))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(5), label("Var5"), delta(1), start(1))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(6), label("Var6"), delta(1), start(1))
  SCALE: linear(dim(1), min(0), max(4.2))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), min(0), max(4.2))
  SCALE: linear(dim(3), min(0), max(4.2))
  SCALE: linear(dim(4), min(0), max(4.2))
  SCALE: linear(dim(5), min(0), max(4.2))
  SCALE: linear(dim(6), min(0), max(4.2))
  ELEMENT: line(position(Var1*Var2*Var3*Var4*Var5*Var6), split(ID), closed(),
           preserveStraightLines())
END GPL.
```

For this example data they both produce quite ugly charts - and there is no obvious need for the polar coordinates given. To make every individual have their own chart the small multiples shown above would not work directly, but the `SPLIT FILE` approach would.

---

For the latest request of adding the mean of all observations here is a potential workflow:

- Use `AGGREGATE` to add 6 more columns for the mean of all variables, e.g. `AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK /VM1 TO VM6 = MEAN(V1 TO V6).`
- When reshaping make two new variables, e.g. `VARSTOCASES /MAKE Var FROM Var1 TO Var6 /MAKE Var2 FROM VM1 TO VM6 /INDEX VarID`.
- In the GGRAPH code add `Var2` to the `VARIABLES` command
- For the inline GPL code add a `DATA` line for `Var2` and make a second line `ELEMENT` displaying the mean.

Comment: Good grief, SPSS "syntax" is so ugly - every time I see it, I want to puke. Unfortunately, I work daily with SPSS

Comment: @ChristianSauer The `GGRAPH` syntax is monstrous yes. The data-management (e.g. `VARSTOCASES`, `AGGREGATE`) is pretty concise, compared to all of the `*pply` functions one has to use in `R`. `GGRAPH` I typically have the GUI build me the base set of specifications, and then I add in the formatting.

Comment: I think they are okay - compared to dplyr, I take dplyr every time. But that isn't much - compared to a good programming language both are pretty horrible. Especially because both have so an inconsistent syntax

Comment: thank you @AndyW. However, I want to create separate spider charts, in separate coordinates. Right now, all cases (id 1-5) are beeing plot in just one single diagramm. But I want to create 5 diagramms, each containing the spider chart of one id with chart of the mean of each id.

I tried it with loops, but I get error regarding GPL.

Comment: There you go @malptek - an example of splitting these up into individual charts. Be warned though - these examples (and most data) would be much clearer just as bar charts in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: woooow Thanks @AndyW for the fast reply :) - just two minor questions:
1. is it possible to add one graph to each diagram, which is calculated by the means of all cases => this is to compare each ID with the mean of the total group.
2. is there a syntax to export all separate diagrams into a folder with ID as the name for each image?

Comment: @malptek If you export images using `OUTPUT EXPORT` it will name the images sequentially (using the `SPLIT FILE` option which makes seperate images). For the second, I will briefly outline a sketch in the answer.